# assign output of command to global array without losing the array after subshell

Tags: linux, bash

I need to read the output of my command to array and store them in order to use after in my script.My script is;

```
  let i=0
  declare -a array
  $PS -ef|$GREP -v grep|$GREP $NAME | $SED -n 's/.*-q\s\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p' | while read line; do
    array[$i]=$line
    echo ${array[$i]}   
    (( i++ ))
    echo ${#array[@]}           
    done < <($PS -ef|$GREP -v grep|$GREP $NAME | $SED -n 's/.*-q\s\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p')  
    echo ${#array[@]}
```

So when the loop exits size of the array becomes 0 because of subshell. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: It's not necessary to maintain an index variable. You can append to an array like this: `array+=("$line")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have identical inputs on both ends of your pipe:

```
foo | while read line; do
    ...
done <( foo )
```

Try dropping the first so that the `while` loop doesn't execute in a subshell:

```
while read line; do
    ...
done <( foo )
```

If you are using bash 4 or higher, you can replace the while loop with a call to `readarray`:

```
readarray array <( foo )
```